# Computed value function in Vue object being triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, computed-properties

I have a Vue object that contains a `computed` property. In the `mounted` function, there is an event that I set up a listener for. The function for the computed property is being called when the event that I'm listening for is triggered, but it's being called *before* the event handler starts its process. The only other reference to the computed property in the object is a watcher. The call stack only shows vue.js processes prior to the computed property being called. As near as I can tell, no values that the computed property is dependent on are being changed.

```
new Vue({
el: '#element',
data: {
    info: [],
},
computed: {
    compVal: function () {
        .
        .
        .
    },
    d
},
watch: {
    compVal: function (dataSet) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    var vm = this;

    window.addEventListener("datachange", function (e) {
        vm.info = e.newInfo;
    });
}})
```

Can someone help me figure out why it is being called so I can prevent it? Or at least help me determine that no dependent values are changing so I can return early from it instead of completing the function?

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added. Like I said, `compVal` is being called when the event is triggered (it's triggered by form elements elsewhere on the page), but before the event handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

If your function should run based on a watcher event, then the function should be located in methods.

Comment: That's just it. It _shouldn't_ run based on a watcher event. The watcher is assigning values that it's dependent on, but the function is running before those values even get assigned, so it ends up being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out.

One of the objects that was being passed in by the event was a reference to the object held by the code that was triggering the event, rather than a copy. When the page first loaded, an initial event with default values was sent. When the Vue object stored those values, it was getting a reference. When the source of the event (a different Vue object that had domain over the form elements) changed its copy of the object, it was automatically triggering the change in the main Vue object’s reference to the object and causing the property to evaluate.

Doing a deep clone of the object before passing it into the event solved it.